# Discord Cache, how long does it last?

Tags: discord.js

```
guild.members.fetch()
```

Returns a cached response. Is there a way to determine how long it takes for the cache to refresh?
Is there a fixed amount of time that passes between regular refreshes?

I am aware that the call returns a promise and must be either awaited or handled with .then(). I was actually wondering about the returned result of the call; how often discord clears it's own cache.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's a cached response and not a real one?

Comment: Hi Alejandro, from my experience. I have attempted in the past to run this method on a densely populated guild (200+ members). The method returns users that aren't present anymore in the guild and not an always updated list. (Discordjs 13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function returns a promise, which resolves when all the members are fetched successfully and the cache is set. Simply `await` this promise to get updated cache.

```js
// note this returns a Collection of the members who were fetched and cached
await guild.members.fetch() 
console.log(guild.members.cache.size) // should log the real amount of members in the server
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I've made my question unclear. I am aware that the call returns a promise and must be either awaited or handled with .then(). I was actually wondering about the returned result of the call; how often discord clears the cache. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @violetflare the cache is only cleared when you restart your bot